# How do you automatically enable writeoom-mode when org-mode starts?

Tags: org-mode, major-mode, minor-mode, writing

I want to enable writeroom-mode whenever I startup org-mode because I don't really ever want writeroom-mode to be disabled if I'm using org-mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `use-package` just add the following to your`~/.emacs` file:

```lisp
(use-package writeroom-mode
  :ensure t
  :init (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'writeroom-mode)
  :after org)
```

If you're not using `use-package` then just put the following line somewhere in your `~/.emacs` file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'writeroom-mode)
```

Comment: If this answer resolved your problem, please accept it.